# Formatting text from Server

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to have text read from `Firebase` on a `Swift3` `iOS` App with special format.

I want to be able to make something like this attached image.

How should I Write my text on `Firebase` `Database`, and how can I interpret it to give it colors, `Bolds, Bullet Points`, Etc? Like if i was HTML content or rich text.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can right tag in your `Firebase` like HTML then display the HTML content using Swift. Or create tag with a regex... I think, using HTML format is more simply in your case

Comment: That sounds like something could work, can you please explain more? Do you have some Example, or a website where I can see something simple to test it out?

Comment: I've post some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use HTML tags to format your text and write it in Firebase.

Your text will be something like this:

```
<h1 style="color:blue;">Your Title</h1>
<p>
    My super description/text
</p>
```

Then write this example in your Firebase.

Now display you HTML content (Swit 2.0):

```
let myHtmlStringContent = "" // Your HTML content from Firebase
var attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: myHtmlStringContent.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
label.attributedText = attrStr // Your IBOutlet
```

Comment: Thanks sound as a good solution, But I have tried and for Example If I have a Video, it says I should enable Javascript, is there a way to do it? Its an embedded you've video, the ones you get on youtube.

Comment: You can search on Google to enable JS... If is helps you, you can mark this answer as solution :)

Comment: You should use a `UIWebView` to be able to show a video. You can go on this way

Comment: Thanks, both solutions help me a lot!